# Parameter from URL Javascript - Form: /index.html#/?id=1426591453147

Tags: javascript, jquery, url, web, parameters

im trying to get a parameter from the current url using JavaScript or jQuery.
The URL looks like this:

```
http://my-site.com/index.html#/?id=1426591453147
```

or

```
http://my-site.com/#/?id=1426591453147
```

I tried a few codes with "location.search", but location.search return an empty string on my urls.

Does anyone know a good solution to this?

**EDIT:**
I ended up using this:

```
function getParameterByName(name) {
    name = name.replace(/[\[]/, "\\[").replace(/[\]]/, "\\]");
    var regex = new RegExp("[\\?]" + name + "=([^&#]*)"),
        results = regex.exec(location.hash);
    return results === null ? "" : decodeURIComponent(results[1].replace(/\+/g, " "));
}
```

Comment: `location.search` works when URL is in form: `example.com?foo=bar`. But your "query string" is preceeded with `#` and therefore, the rest of the string is accessed with `location.hash`.

Comment: `"http://my-site.com/index.html#/?id=1426591453147".replace(/^.*?\.com(.*?)$/i, '$1')`

Comment: I ended up using zvonas's answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Something like this? (**works with your specific case**)

```
"http://my-site.com/index.html#/?id=1426591453147".replace(/^.*?\.com(.*?)$/i, '$1'); // "/index.html#/?id=1426591453147"

"http://my-site.com/#/?id=1426591453147".replace(/^.*?\.com(.*?)$/i, '$1'); // "/#/?id=1426591453147"
```

So,

```
location.href.replace(/^.*?\.com(.*?)$/i, '$1');
```